# Nativescript Angular modal view border radius not working

Tags: modal-dialog, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, angular-nativescript

I am trying to create a modal and have round edges on the modal, but the problem is with the modal container which I cannot seem to access.

Modal Wrapper:

```
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" alignItems="flex-start" justifyContent="space-around" class="wil-modal">
</FlexboxLayout>
```

Wrapper Css:

```
.wil-modal {
  height: 310;
  width: 330;
  border-radius: 30;
  background-color: #3C5AFD;
  border-width: 3;
}
```

[image: Modal has a white square Wrapper]

I want to apply or remove the white wrapper that is containing my Flexbox.

Comment: I believe the issue you are pointing is specific to Android, by default the [window's background color is set to white](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/nativescript-core/ui/core/view/view.android.ts#L218). You will have to reset it to transparent once it's created to avoid the white corners. Also you might want to report this as a parity bug on Github.

Comment: @PrajilShrestha have you found any solution?

Comment: @no_fate we have set a workaround for this, ill post in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

We figured out that wrapping the modal component with a modal stack tag like

```
<modal:ModalStack class="modal-container"> <--- this
<FlexboxLayout>
Modal content here
</FlexboxLayout>
</modal:ModalStack>
```

did the trick.